# How to add volume bar ,radio button and Checkbox  for children in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

I have to design settings  for my application. My settings Group items are  1.Volume settings, 2.Share Settings, 3.Reminder settings. I Have design trough ExpandableListView. In Volume setting i want to provide a volume bar so that i can increase or reduce my volume. For share setting i want to provide checkbox for children . For Reminder setting i want to do that by radio buttons for children. Can you provide code.for that.  here is My smple code.............

```
public class ExpandableListViewDemo4Activity extends Activity {
            private static final String KEY1 = "GROUP";
            private static final String KEY2 = "CHILD";

            //String to be displayed  
            private String[] GROUPS = { "Video Volume Settings", "Reminder Settings", "Share Settings", "Other Settings" };
            private String[][] CHILDREN = {
                    { "low", "mediam", "high"},
                    { "after 5 sec", "after 10 sec", "after 15 sec", "after 30 sec" },
                    { "Facebook", "Twitter", "E-Mail", "Messaging" },
                    { "channel", "news" }
            };


            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                // Setting a list of strings
                List<Map<String, String>> groupData =
                    new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData =
                    new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

                // Continue to set the string to the list
                for (int i = 0; i < GROUPS.length; i++) {
                    //Adding a parent element 
                    Map<String, String> curGroupMap =
                        new HashMap<String, String>();
                    groupData.add(curGroupMap);
                    curGroupMap.put(KEY1, GROUPS[i]);
                    curGroupMap.put(KEY2, "");

                    List<Map<String, String>> children =
                        new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                    if (CHILDREN.length > i) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < CHILDREN[i].length; j++) {
                            //Add a child 
                            Map<String, String> curChildMap =
                                new HashMap<String, String>();
                            children.add(curChildMap);
                            curChildMap.put(KEY1, CHILDREN[i][j]);  
                            j]);                }
                    }
                    childData.add(children);
                }

                // ExpandbleListAdapter create
                ExpandableListAdapter adapter =
                    new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                            this,
                            groupData,
                            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                            new String[] { KEY1, KEY2 },
                            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
                            childData,
                            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                            new String[] { KEY1, KEY2 },
                            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
                    );

                ExpandableListView listView = 
                    (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView);
                // set the Adapter
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                //Register a callback to be called when the user clicks the group 
                listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                            View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                        //What Happens When the user clicks 
                        return false;
                    }      
                });

                //Register a callback to be called when the item is clicked in the group 
                listView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        //What Happens When the user clicks


                        return true;
                    }      
                });
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using Android's built-in preference theme?

Comment: No reason. Im new. I want any type code which fulfillmy requrement.

Comment: I've added an answer with more info on the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out PreferenceActivity and PreferenceManager. Lars Vogel has an excellent tutorial on it:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#preferences